# Hyperledger Fabric peer, peer chaincode commands

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric provides peer, peer chaincode commands: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/commands/peerchaincode.html

I have setup on different VMs. I am using commands like:

peer chaincode query on terminal on one vm
It should show the chaincode for the current value on a peer’s ledger.

Instead I get command not found error. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the terminal doesn't know where to find the peer command. You have to set the $PATH environment variable to indicate the location of the peer binary file. [From the doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/install.html)

> You may want to add that to your PATH environment variable so that these can be picked up without fully qualifying the path to each binary. e.g.: export PATH=/bin:$PATH